# Show that $\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n\in A, (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)=\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1,}...,X_N)\in F|X_n\in A)$

Tags: markov-chains

In our reading we had the following Theorem concerning Markov chains:

> > Take $0<n<N$ and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a Markov chain. Then for all $a_n\in E$ (where $E$ is the state space) and all subsets $G\subseteq E^n, F\subseteq E^{N-n}$ we have that
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n=a_n,(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)\\=\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n=a).
> > $$

Now the following question:

> > Does the statement of the theorem remain true if $\left\{X_n=a\right\}$ is replaced by $\left\{X_n\in A\right\}$ for some arbitrary $A\subseteq E$?

I tried to prove that in the following way using the theorem and the $\sigma$-additicity of $\mathbb{P}$ and $\left\{X_n\in A\right\}=\biguplus_{a_n\in A}(X_n=a_n)$:

$$
\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n\in A,(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)\\=\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|\biguplus_{a_n\in A}(X_n=a_n)\cap(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)\\
=\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|\biguplus_{a_n\in A}[(X_n=a_n)\cap (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G])\\=\frac{\mathbb{P}[(X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F]\cap\biguplus_{a_n\in A}[(X_n=a)\cap (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G])}{\mathbb{P}(\biguplus_{a_n\in A}[(X_n=a_n)\cap (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G])}\\=\frac{\sum_{a_n\in A}\mathbb{P}([(X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F]\cap [ (X_n=a_n)\cap (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G])}{\mathbb{P}(\biguplus_{a_n\in A}[(X_n=a_n)\cap (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G])}\\=\frac{\sum_{a_n\in A}\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n=a_n,(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_n=a_n,(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)}{\mathbb{P}(\biguplus_{a_n\in A}[(X_n=a_n)\cap (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G])}
$$
Now using the theorem I can write the summands as
$$
\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n=a_n,(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)\cdot\mathbb{P}(X_n=a,(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G) =\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n=a_n)\mathbb{P}(X_n=a,(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G),
$$

so I now have
$$
=\frac{\sum_{a_n\in A}\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n=a_n)\cdot \mathbb{P}(X_n=a_n, (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)}{\mathbb{P}(\biguplus_{a_n\in A}[(X_n=a_n)\cap (X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G])}
$$

Do not know how to continue...

Maybe I am not right up to here or maybe the statement does not remain true..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Take $0<n<N$ and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a Markov chain. Then for all $a_n\in E$ (where $E$ is the state space) and all subsets $G\subseteq E^n, F\subseteq E^{N-n}$ we have that
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n=a_n,(X_{n-1},...,X_0)\in G)\\=\mathbb{P}((X_{n+1},...,X_N)\in F|X_n=a).
> > $$
> >     Does the statement of the theorem remain true if $\{X_n = a\}$ is replaced by $\{X_n \in A\}$ for $A \subset E$?

This is, perhaps surprisingly, **not true**, even in trivial cases.

Consider the Markov chain on $\{0,1\}$ with transition kernel given by
$$P(X_{n+1} = 1 \;|\ X_n = 0) = 1, \quad P(X_{n+1} = 0 \;|\ X_n = 1) = 1.$$
Let $P(X_0 = 0) = P(X_0 = 1) = 1/2$. Let $A = \{0, 1\}$. Then
\begin{gather*}
P(X_2 \in \{0\} \;|\ X_1 \in A, X_0 \in \{0\}) = 1,
\end{gather*}
since $X_0 = 0$ implies $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2 = 0$. On the other hand,
\begin{gather*}
P(X_2 \in \{0\} \;|\ X_1 \in A) < 1.
\end{gather*}

Comment: What are $n$ and $N$ in your counter example?

Comment: $N = 2, n = 1$, $F = G = \{0\} \subset \{0,1\}$. If I've understood your question correctly, I don't think the counter-example is hard to interpret.

Comment: Could you please explain me why the second probability is <1? I cannot see it.

Comment: It's actually $1/2$; I wrote $1$ because I thought it would be easier to see. Note that since $A = E$, the whole state space, $P(X_1 \in A) = 1$. Therefore, $P(X_2 = 0 | X_1 \in A) = \frac{P(X_2 = 0, X_1 \in A)}{P(X_1 \in A)} = P(X_2 = 0, X_1 \in A) = P(X_2 = 0)$. This last expression can be expanded as $P(X_2 = 0) = \sum_{i=0}^1 P(X_2 = 0 | X_0 = i) P(X_0 = i) = 1\cdot \frac{1}{2} + 0\cdot \frac{1}{2} = 1/2$.

Comment: Informally, you can think of it as, "if $X_1 \in A$, there is a non-zero probability that $X_1 = 0$, in which case $X_2 = 0$ is impossible," hence $P(X_2 = 0 \;|\ X_1 \in A) < 1$.

Comment: Why is $P(X_2=0,X_1\in A)=P(X_2=0)$?

Comment: Because if $A \subset B$, then $P(A \cap B) = P(A)$. Observe that $\{X_2 = 0\} \subset \{X_1 \in A\}$, because $\{X_1 \in  A\}$ doesn't imply anything at all. It just says "$X_1$ will land in the state space" and that always happens.

Comment: Now I think I got it. Thank you very much for your patience.